# How do special libraries in C cause memory allocation to fail or interact improperly?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, gsl, raylib

Specifically the libraries of GSL and Raylib have special memory allocation functions that include allocs() and free() based on their respective structures and implementations.  However, these are just specific examples, there are times when C memory allocations being used by different components interact and cause segmentation faults even when they are being used properly by the program running them. What is this problem called, why does it occur, and what are the best practices to keep memory allocations from interfering with each other?

Comment: Why do you think your crashes are caused by this?

Comment: It shouldn't happen unless there are bugs. And this is pretty unlikely in popular libraries.

Comment: It's far more likely that the bugs are in your code, and they're causing the libraries to misbehave.

Comment: If the library handles allocation specially somehow or is linked to a different memory allocator, then it generally must provide matched allocation and deallocation functions that you must use with it. Trying to use the library's allocate and standard free() on that object in your code, or vice versa is a bug in your code and could result in the kind of problems you mention.

Comment: If you use an allocator from library A and then free from library B there's no telling what might happen. You should pair A with A, B with B, etc. If you have a structure with elements of both in it, you should probably create a deallocator function that correctly unwinds things in the proper sequence.

Comment: Unless a given library uses _syscalls_ directly for allocation (e.g. `brk/sbrk` or `mmap`), it will ultimately call libc's allocation functions (e.g. `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `free`) at the lowest level. I did a cursory look at GSL. It has _many_ [object specific] allocators but they [AFAICT] _all_ call libc's functions. So, _no_ conflict. These allocators are [loosely] constructors for objects that use standard allocation functions underneath.

Comment: For example, we have `gsl_block_alloc` which allocs `b` and `b->data` (via `malloc`). We must use `gsl_block_free` (that does `free(b->data); free(b);` to properly release/free that object. Manually, calling `free` on the pointer returned by `gsl_block_alloc` would leak `b->data` for example. It seems GSL is well behaved and always has a corresponding `*_free` function for every `*_alloc` function. I didn't look at `raylib` but I suspect it's similar. So, again, no worries. If you're having issues, maybe you're _not_ calling the correct `*free` functions.

Comment: The issue in memory allocation flow is as follows. Create GSL allocations, start Raylib Drawing Loop, loop through GSL driver, draw or plot GSL answers. Close out Raylib drawing loop and free all used allocs.  This workflow fails and causes inconsistent runtime results which cycle through.. working, bus errors, and segmentation faults, then working again.  With no apparent reason why.  Only by running the GSL code, saving the results in an array of arrays, freeing gsl, then starting raylib and drawing from the saved array of arrays, was the program able to work consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are times when C memory allocations being used by different components interact and cause segmentation faults even when they are being used properly by the program running them. What is this problem called, why does it occur, and what are the best practices to keep memory allocations from interfering with each other?

That's usually not the case. Memory allocations do not "interfere with each other" apart from heap memory fragmentation over time, which isn't an error state but can lead to slower access or memory waste.

More commonly there are **bugs in the application** using the library:

- "Out of bounds" bugs, when the application is accessing arrays/pointers out of bounds. Usually leading to "seg fault" on *nix-based systems.
- "Heap corruption" bugs, which is just another flavour of the above, since out of bounds access could cause corrupted data on the heap rather than a seg fault. But this error is also often caused by the application incorrectly assigning the pointer returned from the allocation function to some other memory location, then trying to use/free the invalid pointer.
- "Memory leak" bugs, when the application is not calling the corresponding free() function after it is done using the object.
- "Dangling pointer" bugs, when the application is accessing an object after calling the corresponding free() function in the library.
- "Double free" bugs, where the corresponding free() function of the library is called twice, first on a valid object, next on an invalid object.

Best practices to avoid the mentioned bugs:

- "Clean up your own mess". The code module allocating a resource/opening a file etc is also responsible for cleaning it up. In case of library code, this means that a clean-up function needs to be provided by the library API and what is should be used on should be documented.
- Never assume that "the OS is going to free the resources anyway so I don't need to do that". Yes, it is true that the OS will clean up most such things, *but* if your program does not attempt to free resources, you will not notice a whole lot of the above mentioned bugs either. If you free resources manually then you will spot bugs early on in the development phase and not very late after product release.
- Use bounds-checking if you are unsure if some index variable is within the allocated range.
- Perform input sanitation at the point where your program is taking input.
- Initialize all pointers that are to be used for dynamic allocation to NULL, if they aren't assigned to dynamic memory shortly after the point where they are declared.
- After freeing something, set the pointer to NULL.
- `free(null_pointer)` is a safe no-op - it is guaranteed by C that nothing will happen if you try this.
- Always check the result of malloc (and friends). Or in case of a library allocating the resources, always check the status/error codes returned from it.
- Don't use dynamic allocation just for the heck of it, or in order to micro-manage heap memory consumption. Small amounts of data (<100 bytes or so) typically shouldn't get heap allocated at all, if a fixed max size buffer could as well solve the problem.